# Cartodb - clone table from another user

Tags: carto, database

Is there a way to **clone a table from another user**?

The only way I see is exporting the dataset and importing again into your own account.
This would be a nice feature for teaching, i.e., a simple means for sharing data with your students. It is standard in online coding platforms such as JS Bin...

Answer (score 1):

Yep! All you need is the username and table name and use CartoDB's SQL API like this:

`http://{user name}.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20{table name}&format=csv&filename={whatever you want}`

For instance, I have a table of earthquakes in my account that you can get the CSV for like this:

http://eschbacher.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20all_month_3&format=csv&filename=earthquakes

Once you have that URL, you can directly import the file using CartoDB's [file importer](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor/datasets/) just as you would for any other file with a URL.

Besides the format CSV, you can do GeoJSON (geojson), Shapefile (shp), and more. See CartoDB's SQL API docs for more: http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api/

Datasets also have public pages [like this](https://team.cartodb.com/u/eschbacher/tables/ne_50m_admin_1_states_ak_hi_shift/public) where you can download in the format you want, etc.